# Fomatting issue. Passing values to javascript in php vs div

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am having a problem converting a div to a php variable.  This works great as a div but I need to implement this into my php script to show this if the user is viewing another uses page this will display.

```
          //Check to see if you are tracking this member. 

   $sqlFollow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE follower_id= " .$id. " and myMember = " .$viewerID . " LIMIT 1"); 

   $numTrack = mysql_num_rows($sqlFollow);

   if ($numTrack < 1) {
       $divValue = "Track This Person";
       $onclick = "trackMember";    
                  }
    else          {
       $divValue = "Don't Track Person";
       $onclick = "donttrackMember";
            };

    $display_tracking_option = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick.'"("'.$id.'","'.$viewerID.'");"><span class="follow_b">'.$divValue.'</span></a></div>';
```

Saving this in PHP as a value I am having trouble with the " vs '.

```
    $display_tracking_option = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick ."(\''. $id .'\',\''. $viewerID .'\');"><span class="follow_b">"'.$divValue.'"</span></a></div>';
```

Comment: Are you trying to display actual PHP code **as plain text**? Or are you simply trying to insert PHP variables into the HTML code?

Comment: please explain your problem more (`trouble with the " vs '.`). A side note: you are placing php tags (`<?php ?>`) in a string, where they will not be processed. Also why are you putting this in a variable with two newlines?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Wow! Wish I had seen this article sooner.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the stuff to a variable using php so you don't need to echo anything:

```
$display_tracking_option = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick.'("'.$id.'","'.$viewerID.'");"><span class="follow_b">'.$divValue.'</span></a></div>';
```

Simply concatenate the string.

Alternatively you could use [`sprintf()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$theString = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="%s("%s","%s");"><span class="follow_b">%s</span></a></div>'
$display_tracking_option = sprintf($theString, $onclick, $id, $viewerID, $divValue);
```

Another thing: why do you have inline stuff?

Comment: I am passing two values to a javascript that will update the tracking of a post or member.  When the script returns the div hides and is updated that the user is now tracking the object.  The button displays but it not firing off the javascript or the values are not being passed. correctly.  Looking up the sprintf stuff. The above failed to work.   I was not thinking by putting and echo inside the php.

Comment: I updated my original post to show the sql.  This is a very simple script.  The javascrpt just passes to values and update the datebase.  Returns and if sucessful the div is updated to show that the user is now being tracked.

Comment: I used your example after my brain fart and just removed some double quotes from the variables. 

          $display_tracking_option = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick.'('.$id.','.$viewerID.');"><span class="follow_b">'.$divValue.'</span></a></div>';

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
$display_tracking_option = '<div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick.'("'.$id.'","'.$viewerID.'");"><span class="follow_b">'.$divValue.'</span></a></div>';
```

Comment: Closer.  The values are not passing to the javascript. I have also tried this

          $display_tracking_option = ' <div class="track_btn_div" id="addremoveTrack"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="'. $onclick .'"(\''. $id .'\',\''. $viewerID .'\');"><span class="follow_b">"'.$divValue.'"</span></a></div>';